# Get array out of a JSON

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

I wrote a piece of code which extract some value out of JSON file.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    x=0
    for response_i in response['response']:
        num_dimentions=3
        while x <= num_dimentions-1:
            if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues':
                dims=response_i['objcontent'][x]['title']
                print(dims) 

dimensions=[dim]
print(dimensions)
```

the out put of print(dims) is:

```
lat
lon
time
```

The out put of print(dimensions) is:

```
['time']
```

I expected to get:

```
['lat', 'lon', 'time']
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `'time'` to your `dims` variable on your last iteration.

If you want to get a list of all those items, create a list and append to it.

```
dimensions = []

if __name__=='__main__':
    x=0
    for response_i in response['response']:
        num_dimentions=3
        while x <= num_dimentions-1:
            if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues':
                dimensions.append(response_i['objcontent'][x]['title'])

print(dimensions)
```